# Retain draggable div position

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable

I have a jquery draggable div and i want the position to be saved (maybe in a cookie) because every time I refresh the page the div is re-positioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the position using left and top:

```
$('#divID').left
$('#divID').top
```

Then you can store it with the [jQuery cookie plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie) or using [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Answer (score 0):

look at http://www.vicsjavascripts.org.uk/DragDropSort/DragDropSort.htm which uses a cookie to remember the last sorted positions.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#divID').position().left;
$('#divID').position().top;
```

Store the information in a cookie, url fragment or something else. An idea could be to use the callback-function from the draggable-plugin and do an ajax-call to a php-script that sets the cookie.